# Collision testing on Objects instead of Instances

Tags: java

I am trying to customize a collider class, where you can pass two objects to a method, and if any of the two collide, perform some sort of action.

For example I am making a shooter game, and what I would like to do is say:

- If Any `Ship` Collides with any bullet `Bullet`

  - Destroy both the affected `Ship` and the affected `Bullet`
- Else

  - Do nothing

What I would like to do is write this once, and not for every bullet and/or ship. So, I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
ColliderEvent collide = new ColliderEvent();
collide.hit(Ship, Bullet, new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // Destroy bullet and ship here
    }
});
```

Then in my main game thread, I would do something that would test if two objects that were provided in some sort of `hit` method collide at some point, and if so perform the third parameter passed into `hit`

So, is there any way to do this without passing in an instance of Ship/Bullet to the `hit` method?

Comment: Assuming a ship is larger than a bullet, you could create a `Position` object, have a ship return a `Set<Position>` method and check whether a bullet's position is contained within a ship's position set? This would of course imply that `Position` correctly implements `equals()` and `hashCode()`...

Comment: I agree.. and if you wanted to, you could create an onCollision() function for all the objects and implement it in a superclass.

Comment: I have the feeling that you just want to execute this method for every ship/bullet combination. Two nested loops will make this done.

Comment: I didn't mention in the main question, but this is for a library, so I would really like this to work with different games and game types.

Comment: What about creating your own events and listeners for different game events?

Comment: How would I do that? I am fairly new to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using [events and listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) to handle something like this in your library.  Basically, you would have a class that checks the entire map for a collision.  If there is a collision, it calls a method (you implement) in the object classes (bullet or ship e.g.), telling them that they collided.